# URL Rewriting, SEO and encoding

Tags: url-rewriting, urlencode, seo

I found this [article regarding URL Rewriting](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/02/26/tip-trick-url-rewriting-with-asp-net.aspx) most useful.
But here are a couple of questions.

I would love to use a URL (before rewriting, with spaces inside the query string)

```
http://www.store.com/products.aspx?category=CD s-Dvd s
```

First of all, should I replace the spaces with the plus sign (`+`) for any reason? Like this:

```
http://www.store.com/products.aspx?category=CD+s-Dvd+s
```

Secondly, my native language is Greek. Should I encode the parameters? Generally speaking, would the result with URL encoding on be different, regarding S.E.O.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the value must come through unaltered, then yes you must use escaping. In a URL query parameter value, a space may be encoded as `+` or `%20`. mod_rewrite will generally do this for you as long as the external version was suitably spelled.

In the external version of the URL, only %20 can be used:

```
http://www.store.com/products/CD%20s-Dvd%20s
http://www.store.com/products.php?category=CD%20s-Dvd%20s
```

because a `+` in a URL path part would literally mean a plus.

(Are you sure you want a space there? “CDs-DVDs” without the spaces would seem to be a better title.)

It is non-trivial to get arbitrary strings through from a path part to a parameter. Apart from the escaping issues, you've got problems with `/`, which should be encoded as `%2F` in a path part. However Apache will by default block any URL containing `%2F` for security reasons. (`\` is similarly affected under Windows.) You can turn this behaviour off using the `AllowEncodedSlashes` config, but it means if you want to be portable you can't use “CDs/DVDs” as a category name.

For this reason, and because having a load of `%20`​s in your URL is a bit ugly, strings are usually turned into ‘slugs’ before being put in a URL, where all the contentious ASCII characters that would result in visible %-escapes are replaced with filler characters such as hyphen or underscore. This does mean you can't round-trip the string, so you need to store either a separate title and slug in the database to be able to look up the right entity for a given slug, or just use an additional ID in the URL (like Stack Overflow does).

Answer (score 1):

Actually you should replace spaces with hyphens. That actually is better for SEO than using an underscore.

Answer (score 0):

General practice is to replace spaces with underscores, ala `http://www.store.com/products.aspx?category=CD_s-Dvd_s`